# Dictionary to JSON object conversion

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have 2 long lists (extracted from a csv) both of the same index length. 
Example:

```
l1 = ['Apple','Tomato','Cocos'] #name of product

l2 = ['1','2','3'] #some id's
```

I made my dictionary with this method:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for x in l1:
    d['Product'].append(x)
for y in l2:
    d['Plu'].append(y)
print d
```

This will output:

**{'Product': ['Apple', 'Tomato', 'Cocos'], 'Plu': ['1', '2', '3']}**

(`Product` and `Plu` are my wanted keys)

Now I've tried to import this to a JavaScript Object like this:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

This will output:

```js
{
    "Plu": [
        "1", 
        "2", 
        "3"
    ], 
    "Product": [
        "Apple", 
        "Tomato", 
        "Cocos"
    ]
}
```

But my desired output is this:

```js
  {
    Product:'Apple',
    Plu:'1'
  },
  {
    Product:'Tomato',
    Plu:'2'
  },
  {
    Product:'Cocos',
    Plu:'3'
  }
```

I will later use that to insert values in a MongoDB. What will I have to change in my json.dump (or in my dict?) in order to get a desired output? Also is there a way to save the output in a txt file? (since I will have a big code).

Comment: @jherax This is not a JS question!

Comment: @Bergi you are right, thanks for fix the tags +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a `defaultdict` (which doesn't buy you anything in this case), you're better off `zip`ping the lists and creating a `dict` from each pair:

```
[{'Product': product, 'Plu': plu} for product, plu in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Comment: I will get then a list of dicts, how I can convert that later into a javascript object?

Comment: @iRocku -- You can `json.dumps` it and then put it into your HTML/Javascript file somehow....

Comment: oh wow, it works, is there any possibility to remove the [] at the start and end when I generate my javascript object ?

Comment: @iRocku -- Not if you want it to be valid javascript ... with that said, you _can_ just slice off the first and last character after using `json.dumps`...

Comment: A thing thou, can I have the Product and Plu without '' '' ? Like a strip or something.

Comment: Are they all integers?  you can use `... 'Plu': int(plu)} ...`

Comment: I mean not to strip his value, I want to strip 'Plu' to Plu on the javascript obj!

Comment: @iRocku -- There's not a builtin way to do that.  You'd have to write some separate code that works _like_ `json.dumps`, but encodes objects slightly differently.

Comment: Since the javascript obj its a string, I will try to write a regex that will strip '' from Plu and Product.

Comment: It's probably non-trivial to do that in the general case.  In this simple case, you might be able to just do:  `json.dumps(...).replace('"Plu"', 'Plu').replace('"Product"', 'Product')`

Comment: perfect, thanks alot! Thing is that I need them without '''' for the mongodb insert.